# Replace an unknown number of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I am trying to replace a number of parts of an array with one number. I am making a calculator and I want to replace a pair of brackets and the content between the brackets with the sum of the content. Replace (2*2+4) with 8. The array is containing a value of (, 2, *, 2, +, 4, ) and I want this to become only 8. I am using javascript and I hope someone has any idea of how to solve this.
Best regards!

Comment: You need to evaluate the tokens. To do this you ned to turn them into tokens (which you more or less have, but perhaps there is a better representation). Then you need to turn them into a representation that can be evaluated - either Reverse Polish Notation (`*`, `2`, `2`, `+`, `4`) or even a tree. Finally, evaluate them. This is not exactly *trivial* and each step can fill in *several* questions. Parsing mathematical equations is one of the easier parsing problems but it's still a rather big topic.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the content of your array could be pretty easily mapped into a valid JavaScript expression. If that holds true, then you could use the JavaScript interpreter to evaluate the expression and yield the answer you want. For example:

```
var myArray = ['(', '2', '*', '2', '+', '4', ')'];
var myExpression = myArray.join(' ');
var myResult = window.eval(myExpression);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use anoter array for nested parts and calculate each part if a closing parentesis is found.

```js
var array = ['(', '2', '*', '2', '+', '4', ')'],
    nested = [[]],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === ')') {
        nested[nested.length - 2].push(eval(nested[nested.length - 1].join('')));
        nested.length--;
        continue;
    }
    if (array[i] === '(') {
        nested.push([]);
        continue;
    }
    nested[nested.length - 1].push(array[i]);
}

console.log(nested);
```